# Cannot Use Kendo UI Scheduler Custom View

Tags: kendo-ui, angular5

I am trying to follow the official doc to learn how to use a custom view on scheduler. But the catch is that I am using it in Angular 5 and importing the view from a JS script. So, I am getting the following error - https://pastebin.com/p4gLuKfv

```
ERROR Error: There is no such view
at init._initializeView (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.scheduler.js:3969)
at init._renderView (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.scheduler.js:3915)
at init._selectView (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.scheduler.js:3871)
at init.view (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.scheduler.js:3899)
```

The JS file is this - https://pastebin.com/Xy9tcY6J

The Angular Component File is this - https://pastebin.com/0p1xHPus

It would be helpful, if someone can point me to why the error is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that CustomMonthView could not be found. So, I added this inside function definition in kendo.customMonthView.js -

```
$.extend(true, ui, {
    CustomMonthView: CustomMonthView
```

});

Additionally, referenced the view type in angular component as 'kendo.ui.CustomMonthView'.